# How can i disable 100's of product in my site

Tags: magento-1.9, products, status

I need to disable some products from my website, is there any bulk edit options in admin panel?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change the product status in two ways.

1. Through admin panel at catalog-->manage products section
2. Through Excel sheet by import/export process.

**For method 1:** Go to `catalog > Mange Products` select the products you want to disable , then you can see `update attributes` opton at right. click on `update attributes` then you will redirect to new page there you can see an option to disable , just select that and save it.

[image]

**For method 2:** If you want to update through excel sheet,

Go to `system >import/export > Dataflow profiles` , then click on `Add new Profile` and give the information as like other profiles.

Enter the Name, select `Type` as `CSV/Tab separated` under `Filed Mapping` click on `Add Field Mapping` , then follow according to below image. then save it. in excel sheet, give information as `Enabled` or `Disabled`. than go to`upload profile` option, then select the excel sheet and click on `save profile`. then go to `Run Profile option` & click on `Run profile in pop-up`.
[image]

Comment: I need to disable 100's of product, is there any bulk edit options by using Excel sheet.

Comment: check my update.